# Making a automated live chat / fake chat and my javascript is skipping the first response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The piece of code I wrote for automating responses to questions is skipping the first response.

Another thing I'd like it to do is hiding the `sendButton` after the last message in the array is send.
I tried putting a .hide() in the message array, hoping it will use it as a last response to disable the button, but this did not seem to do anything besides messing up the code haha.

If someone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#typing").hide();
      var n = "You:<br>";
      var o = $('#outputWindow');
      var i = $('#inputWindow');
      var s = $('#sendButton');
      var t = $('#typing');      
      var r = 0;

      //arrays
      var msg = ['msg1<br />', 'msg2<br />', 'msg3<br />'];

      //fire send events
      $(s).click(function() {
      runAI();
      });
      $(i).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            runAI();
      }
      });

      function runAI() {
      if (i.val().length > 0) {
            r = r + 1;
            o.html(o.html()+n+$("#inputWindow").val()+"<br><hr>" );      
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").show();  }, 3000);            
            i.val('');
            i.focus();
      }
      }
      i.focus();
    });
```

Comment: Why do you wrap the thing in both window.load and document.ready events?

Comment: we dont want to see your entire code, we just want to see the exact problem you have. and also, one question per question so skip the hide question for now.

Comment: edit: misread. and Juhana I used bits and pieces of code around the internet, I am still learning :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, I set r = 0 in the OP.
I went ahead and changed it to -1 and now it isn't skipping the first response anymore.

This is because it starts counting from 1 instead of 0 in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Automated Chat</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#typing").hide();
      var n = "You:<br>";
      var o = $('#outputWindow');
      var i = $('#inputWindow');
      var s = $('#sendButton');
      var t = $('#typing');      
      var r = 0;

      //arrays
      var msg = ['msg0<br />','msg1<br />', 'msg2<br />', 'msg3<br />'];

      //fire send events
      $(s).click(function() {
          i.hide();
            s.hide();
      runAI();
      });
      $(i).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            runAI();
            i.hide();
            s.hide();
      }
      });

      function runAI() {
      if (i.val().length > 0) {

            r = r + 1;
            o.html(o.html()+n+$("#inputWindow").val()+"<br><hr>" );      
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").show();  }, 1000);            
            setTimeout(function(){ o.html(o.html()+"Username:<br>"+msg[r]+"<hr>") }, 3000);
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").hide();i.show();s.show();i.val(''); i.focus(); }, 3000);



      }
      }
      i.focus();
    });
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="outputWindow"></div>
      <input type="text" id="inputWindow"></input>
      <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Send Message"/>
      <div id="typing">Username is typing..</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's done.

Comment: No Snowlav ,it's because the msg array stores 'msg1<br />' in 2nd position whose index is 1,(as incremented from 0).Just put another string in that array in 0 th index and it will work fine

Comment: changing `var r = 0;` to `var r = -1;` did a better job

Comment: wrong convention.Another thing we can do with the actual code ,just increment r in last setTimeOut function